# Setting best display mode as default

Tags: 14.04, xorg, display, xrandr, mode

I use two resolutions - 1680x1050x60Hz for general usage and 1280x1024x75Hz for CS:GO playing.
I have set 1280x1024 in CS:GO settings, but when it launches it sets itself at 60Hz.

For this moment I have found a quick & dirty fix:

> xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 75

This sets current display mode to 1280x1024x75Hz, but I need to do it before every launch of the game and I need to make these changes back as I close my game.

Here is my xrandr -q info:

```
muttley@muttley-desktop:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)     470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050      59.9 +   60.0* 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Is there a way to make Ubuntu switch to correct refresh rate by itself?
Like when I give this command to terminal:

> xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1280x1024

It would automatically pick 75Hz over 60Hz (so when game launches in 1280x1024 it would start at 75Hz, even though 1680x1050x60Hz was set before).

I was thinking about removing those default display modes, so

> xrandr -q

would give me this:

```
muttley@muttley-desktop:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)     470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050      60.0+* 
   1280x1024      75.0
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

But I didn't manage to get access to it (googled for many hours without any luck)

Sorry for my English (Not my native language :/)

Thanks in advance for any help,
muttley

Comment: It would be relatively easy to automatically change the settings when a certain application runs, and set back if not. Is that what you mean? If so, can you make an educated guess what is the process name from `ps -u <yourname>` when the application is running?